# Relationship with [NotMapped] and [Keyless] ends up with NULL object in aspnet core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Using aspnet core webapi, there is a class without an Id called `CustomRegistryKey` that is used as an `ICollection<T>` in another class called `WindowsBase`. When I was compiling I learned about the `[Keyless]` decorator that was required as I didn't include the `public int Id {get;set}` line when creating the class.

The hope was that I would be able to generate an object, and insert it directly into the table and retrieve later when using `GET` request on the API controller.

When a `PUT` command is issued, and the object is converted to JSON and the payload is received, the API always returns `NULL` on the `CustomRegistryKey` ICollection in the returned data.

The classes below are simplified versions of the actual classes for brevity. Having tried removed the `[Keyless]` and the `[NotMapped]` decorators from each class threw errors either at compile or when trying to GET/PUT on the api controller.

How do I go about creating an object, that is not referencing another table, to create an object that does not need to be indexed, but can be retrieved using `GET` calls so the data in the Collection can be iterated through and read like a dictionary/array?

###### CustomRegistryKey.cs

```cs
[Keyless]
public class CustomRegistryKey
{
    public string Hive { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string ValueType { get; set; }
}
```

###### WindowsBase.cs

```cs
public class WindowsBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Release { get; set; }
    
    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<CustomRegistryKey> CustomRegistryKeys { get; set; }
}
```

When I tried to remove **[NotMapped]** the API will compile, but a **GET** will return this kind of error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'WindowsBase.CustomRegistryKeys' of type 'ICollection<CustomRegistryKey>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

Using `Invoke-RestMethod` and creating an object to publish to the API works fine:

```
$CSR1 = @{
  Hive = "HKLM"
  Key = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows"
  ValueType = "REG_SZ"
}
$CSR2 = @{
  Hive = "HKLM"
  Key = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Adobe"
  ValueType = "REG_SZ"
}
$Body = @{
  Id = 0
  Status = "Working"
  Release = "2022"
  CustomRegistryKeys = @($CSR1,$CSR2)
} | ConvertTo-Json
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://localhost/api/WindowsBase -Method Put -Body $Body
```

The output from the `GET` request will look like this everytime, even with a successful `PUT` request:

```json
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "status": "Working",
      "release": "2022",
      "customregistrykeys": null
    }
]
```

The reason I haven't included an `Id` on the CustomRegistryKey class comes from there is not table/controller setup for this to be referenced. I just wanted the object stored in the table so I can call it when it's required.

If I add the `Id`, does not the object need to exist under its own Controller first and be referenced? Is there something I have overlooked or a missing?

Comment: You cannot join a relation that has no relation. The attribute [NotMapped] when you removed, EF wil consider it must be a relation while there is no `key` for this `CustomRegistryKey` object the relation does not heppen, but error instead.

Answer (score 0):

**This relation is many to one, then it should be**
Change to this

```
[Keyless]
public class CustomRegistryKey
{
    public string Hive { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string ValueType { get; set; }
    public virtual WindowsBase WindowsBase { get; set;}
}
```

Change to this

```
public class WindowsBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Release { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<CustomRegistryKey> CustomRegistryKeys { get; set; }
}
```